# ¿Por qué estas líneas evitan que se mueva mi jlabel?

Tags: java, jlabel

Tengo un problema. Estoy haciendo una ventana que cada vez que se hace un click se mueva el jlabel del emoji y se sume uno al contador.
Probando me di cuenta que son esas dos líneas las que no permiten a mi JLabel moverse.

Los métodos usados son estos:

```
 private void etiqueta_emojiMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    // <-- ERROR
    //Iniciamos el tiempo
    tiempo.start();
    
    //Refrescamos el contador
    contadorClicks++;// ERROR -->
    refrescarContadorClicks();

    //Borramos los titulos
    lbl_titulo.setText("");
    lbl_empezar.setText("");

    //Generamos la pos. aleatoria
    xAleatorio = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 599 + 1);
    yAleatorio = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 398 + 1);
    
    etiqueta_emoji.setLocation(xAleatorio, yAleatorio);
    System.out.println(xAleatorio + "-" + yAleatorio);
}

private void refrescarContadorClicks() {
    String text = "Capturas: " + (contadorClicks <= 9 ? "0" : "") + contadorClicks;
    lbl_conteo_capturas.setText(text);
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿De qué clase es `tiempo`?

Comment: Es de la clase Timer